# Pandas dataframe with calculated values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
commission = 2%,
growth = 10%,
start_price = 100,
current_transaction = 1000
```

I wanted to create columns (transaction, revenue)

My question is how to create a dataframe with above information for 3 years.

| Element | Year 1 | Year 2 | Year 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Transaction | 1100 | 1210 | 1331 |
| Revenue | 2200 | 2420 | 2662 |

formula for transaction (transaction X growth) e.g(1000 X 10%)

formula for revenue (transaction X commission X price) e.g(1100X 2% X 100)

the year 2 column is outcome of year 1 ..so on.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic exponential growth series. You can leverage numpy broadcasting to compute them:

```
# Convert all percentages into decimals
commission = 0.02
growth = 0.1
start_price = 100
current_transaction = 1000

# We are going to rely on numpy broadcasting to help us do computations on
# arrays
year = np.arange(1,4)
factor = (1 + growth) ** year

# And make the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Transaction": current_transaction * factor,
    "Revenue": current_transaction * factor * commission * start_price
}, index=year).T.add_prefix("Year ")
```